# Can't upload a file in TinyMCE...?

Tags: javascript, php, json, tinymce

Having an issue with uploading images on Tiny. I want to upload the images to folder /images/owner/ I don't want a blob, but rather to upload full files.

I can upload to file_upload.php no problem from test.html. Containing a text input and a file input only. file_upload.php looks like this ...

```
<?php
  /***************************************************
   * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
   ***************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "https://example.com/");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $owner_id=$_POST["owner"];

  //$owner_id='15601a2cc3d5b2';
  $imageFolder = "images/". $owner_id . "/";

  // Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    return;
  }

  reset($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Determine the base URL
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $baseurl . $filetowrite));

  } else {

    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");

  }

?>
```

This Tiny JS code is on my editor.php page. I don't want a blob that can't be linked to. I want to send an email newsletter and only proper files/images on the server will render...

```
  <script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  images_upload_handler: images_upload_handler,
  plugins: 'image code',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | link image',
  /* enable title field in the Image dialog*/
  image_title: true,
  /* enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs*/
  automatic_uploads: true,
  /*
    URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
    images_upload_url: './js/tinymce/postAcceptor.php',
    here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
  */
  file_picker_types: 'image',
  /* and here's our custom image picker*/
  file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    /*
      Note: In modern browsers input[type=\"file\"] is functional without
      even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
      or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
      just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
      once you do not need it anymore.
    */

    input.onchange = function () {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        /*
          Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
          registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
          necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        */
        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    input.click();
  },
  content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
 
});


function images_upload_handler (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
  var xhr, formData;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST','https://example.com/myfolder/file-upload.php');

  xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
  };

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var json;

    if (xhr.status === 403) {
      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, { remove: true });
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
      failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
      return;
    }

    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
      failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
      return;
    }

    success(json.location);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    failure('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
  };

  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('owner','" . $owner_id . "');
  formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
  
xhr.send(formData);
};
```

When i do this from chrome web dev ...

```
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;
  xhr.open('POST','https://example.com/myfolder/file-upload.php');
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('owner','ddddddddd');
  formData.append('file', '/home/me/Desktop/image/mail.png');
  xhr.send(formData);
```

I get `array(0) {}`

I can't send both values, owner and file. I've stacked them in the correct order.

Also have to click upload on the Tiny editor image popup, when i use General it gives me a blob.

No luck. Sorry if this post is kinda verbose. Thought you'd need all the code to help...